# Insert Into and Select Oracle: Insert only Ids without unique constraint violation

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables `deparments` and `deparments_copy`:

```
SQL> select * from departments;
ID DESCRIPTION
 1 description1
 2 description2
 3 description3
 4 description4
 5 description5
 6 description6
 7 description7
 8 description8
 9 description9
10 description10
11 description11

SQL> select * from departments_copy;
ID DESCRIPTION
 1 description_copy1
 5 description_copy2
10 description_copy3
```

For the `ID` I have an unique constraint:

```
alter table departments_copy add constraint pk_dp_copy primary key (id);
```

If I use the `insert into select` syntax of oracle, I will get an expected unique constraint error. Is it possible to insert only the elements that have no unique constraint violation by using `insert select` syntax?

```
 SQL> insert into departments_copy select * from departments order by id;
insert into departments_copy select * from departments order by id
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (UBU.PK_DP_COPY) violated
```

The result should look like this:

```
SQL> select * from departments_copy;
ID DESCRIPTION
 1 description_copy1
 2 description2
 3 description3
 4 description4
 5 description_copy2
 6 description6
 7 description7
 8 description8
 9 description9
10 description_copy3
11 description11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to use the `MERGE` Statement here. I see you tagged Oracle and SQL Server both. The following command runs in SQL Server.

```
MERGE INTO departments_copy DC
USING (select * from departments) D
ON D.ID = DC.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (DC.ID,DC.DESCRIPTION)
VALUES (D.ID,D.DESCRIPTION)
```

Edited

Comment: With you query it was not working, but this query worked for me: **merge into departments_copy dc using (select * from departments order by id) d on (dc.id=d.id)  when not matched then insert (dc.id,dc.description) values (d.id,d.description);**  I found it here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF55042  thanks

Comment: which database is it?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: there's still a little error in your edit: just change the last line to values(d.id,d.description), because e is not defined then it should work -:)